# express.js on Debian Jessie is saved to invalid location

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian

I'm following the guide found at: [express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html)
My `$NODE_PATH` is appropriately set in my `.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -x NODE_PATH $NODE_PATH /usr/local/node-v5.4.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules
```

and both `node` and `npm` work fine.

However, when I install `express` and `express-generator` for some bizzare reason it seems to be saved under:

```
node_modules/
             express/
             express-generator/
             npm/
```

All my other node modules are within `npm/` why are `express` and `express-generator` being saved outside it?
As you can imagine, calling `express` from command line doesn't work.
Have I broken something?

Comment: did you installl `express-generator` using `-g` parameter ?

Comment: yes, with both `-g` and `--save`. Its there just in the wrong directory

Comment: `-g` forces the installtion in the global `node_modules` folder for your current user.

Comment: @MukeshSharma It installs fine in the local directory (`.npm-global`) but invoking it doesn't work, although I export the local path as well.
AFAIK `sudo npm install -g` moves into the system path not the local `.npm-global`